# Plot rolling mean together with data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
####delays:
            Worst case  Avg case
2014-10-27    2.861433  0.953108
2014-10-28    2.899174  0.981917
2014-10-29    3.080738  1.030154
2014-10-30    2.298898  0.711107
2014-10-31    2.856278  0.998959
2014-11-01    3.118587  1.147104
...
```

I would like to plot the data of this DataFrame, together with the rolling mean of the data. I would like the data itself should be a dotted line and the rolling mean to be a full line. The worst case column should be in red, while the average case column should be in blue.

I've tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rolling = pd.rolling_mean(delays, 7)
delays.plot(x_compat=True, style='r--')
rolling.plot(style='r')
plt.title('Delays per day on entire network')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Minutes')
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, this gives me 2 different plots. One with the data and one with the rolling mean. Also, the worst case column and average case column are both in red.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to say to pandas where you want to plot. By default pandas creates a new figure.

Just modify these 2 lines:

```
delays.plot(x_compat=True, style='r--')
rolling.plot(style='r')
```

by:

```
ax_delays = delays.plot(x_compat=True, style='--', color=["r","b"])
rolling.plot(color=["r","b"], ax=ax_delays, legend=0)
```

in the 2nd line you now tell pandas to plot on ax_delays, and to not show the legend again.

To get 2 different colors for the 2 lines, just pass as many colors with `color` argument (see above).

Comment: I would like both the data and the rolling mean of the worst case column to be red. Also, the data and the rolling mean of the avg case column to be blue. Do I have to plot each column individually for this?