# How do I plot a moving average in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, moving-average

How do I make a moving average of y_pred_org and plot it? I have tried this in the following way but receive an error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rolling' I am sure this is something small but I am new to this.

```
# Visualize the prediction with rolling average
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
['y_pred_org'].rolling(window=50).mean().plot()
plt.plot(y_test_t_org)
plt.title('Prediction vs Real Stock Price')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.legend(['Prediction', 'Real'], loc='upper left')
#plt.show()
```

How should I adjust this for it to function properly?
The following code will function properly .shift(whatever shift you need) can also be added if a phase shift is needed

```
# Visualize the prediction with rolling average
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
df = DataFrame(data = y_pred_org)
df.rolling(30, center=True).mean().plot()
plt.plot(y_test_t_org)
plt.title('Prediction vs Real Stock Price')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.legend(['Prediction', 'Real'], loc='upper left')
#plt.show()
```

Comment: This question may be of help: [Plot rolling mean together with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417763/plot-rolling-mean-together-with-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is in a pandas DataFrame you can use a built in rolling average.

```
df['Y_Predict'] = df.iloc[:,col].rolling(window=5).mean()
```

Comment: I have edited the question to attempt to show what this has led me to try. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Is that the full error message you receive? I think you need to pass the rolling average data as an argument plot().

Comment: The error was: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rolling'  with this code

Comment: Your data needs to be in a dataframe for my suggestion to work properly. See Pandas library

Comment: Thank you @KillerToilet both for your name and for helping me solve this problem!!